# I need to find Maximum and Minimum value Rowwise

Tags: python, shell, awk

```
operator1,4578
operator2,1234
operator3,9875
operator4,6357
operator1,6353
operator4,9765
operator1,6347
operator1,6798
operator3,6793
operator3,1465
operator4,6796
operator4,3333
```

I need to find out minimum and maximum value of each operator using `awk` and `python` (need command in `awk` as well in `Python` too) and output will be as below :

```
Name        Min     Max
operator1   4578    6798 
operator2   1234    
operator3   1465    9875 
operator4   3333    9765
```

Can anyone help me out please

Comment: look up dicts in python and associative arrays in awk

Comment: Max value for operator2 in output is missing. It should be 1234.

Comment: Hi Jose, I did  awk -F "," 'BEGIN { max = -1; min = -1 } 
  $1 == "operator1" {
    max = max < $2 ? $2 : max;
    min = (min == -1 || min > $2) ? $2 : min
  }
  END { printf "operation2  %d %d", max, min }
' filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
awk -F, '
   min[$1]>$2||!min[$1]{
      min[$1]=$2
   } 
   max[$1]<$2{
      max[$1]=$2
   } 
   END{
     for(i in max){
        print i,min[i],(max[i]!=min[i]?max[i]:"")
     }
   }' file
```

This script make used of 2 array `min` and `max` which are filled with values while parsing the input file.

When parsing is finished, both array are printed.

Note that `max[i]!=min[i]?max[i]:""` is skipping the max value in case this is the same as the min one.

I let you put the header line, and play with `column` command in case you want indentation...

Answer (score 0):

@amit kumar: Try:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=A[$1]>$NF?A[$1]:$NF;B[$1]=B[$1]>$NF?$NF:(B[$1]?B[$1]:$NF);next} FNR==1 && FNR!=NR{print "Name Min Max"}($1 in A){print $1 "\t" B[$1] "\t" A[$1];delete B[$1];delete A[$1]}'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Here I am making field separator as a "," then FNR==NR condition will make sure that it gets executed only when first time Input_file is being read. where FNR and NR both are awk's in-built keywords and define the line numbers in it. FNR's value will be RESET whenever a new Input_file being read where N's value will be keep on increasing till all the files being read successfully. Then in that block I am creating an array named A whose index is $1 and where I am checking if previous A[$1]'s value is greater than current same index of array compare to $NF then change A[$1]'s value to current $NF as keep it as it is(this is basically for having maximum values for each $1 of line), same thing I am doing to get the MINIMUM values for $1 in Input_file and storing values into array B. next will be skipping all the next coming statements so only FNR==NR condition will be executed.
Now FNR==1 && FNR!=NR condition will be only TRUE when second file's 1st line is being read because before writing actual output I need to write the heading columns. ($1 in A) now checking if current line's $1 is present in array A then print the current $1 and array A's value and then array B's value as per OP's request.

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{
                 A[$1]=A[$1]>$NF?A[$1]:$NF;
                 B[$1]=B[$1]>$NF?$NF:(B[$1]?B[$1]:$NF);
                 next
                }
         FNR==1 && FNR!=NR{
                                print "Name Min Max"
                          }
         ($1 in A){
                        print $1 "\t" B[$1] "\t" A[$1];
                        delete B[$1];
                        delete A[$1]
                  }
        '    Input_file  Input_file
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder, Thanks for detail explanation but the code is not giving any output and moreover, its just one file not two file

Comment: Correct amit, it is 1 file but I am reading it twice, try it out, it should fly. Let me know on same. Also why I am reading the Input_file 2 times because it will give the output in same sequence which is present in Input_file, else if you read an array it will not print the elements in an order.